# Highlight Active/Selected link with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m using this menu in my site

```
<div class="q-nav-bar">
<div class="q-nav-bar-item"><a href="#">Home Page</a></div>
<div class="q-nav-bar-item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
<div class="q-nav-bar-item"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
</div>
```

and this code to highlight the selected links:

```
$(function(){
        $(\'.q-nav-bar-item a\').each(function(){
            if ($(this).prop(\'href\') == window.location.href) {
            $(this).addClass(\'selected\'); 
            $(this).parents(\'a\').addClass(\'selected\');
            }
        });
    });
```

It works OK but how can i apply the "selected" rule to the home link by default every time a new quest visit my page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $link = $('a');

$link.on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // stop normal link function (#)
  $link.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.default').trigger('click');
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class='default'>Link #1</a>
<a href="#">Link #2</a>
```